# Convert masked image to LabelMe json file output

Tags: image, label, image-segmentation, typeconverter

I want to convert the Mask predicted by my model into a JSON file of LabelMe type for fine-tuning and training again. How can I do this? Here is an example of an image:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6hwb.png)

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve coordinates of the contour of the mask with like [opencvfindContours()](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/df/d0d/tutorial_find_contours.html) function and put in a json file for labelme.
For complexes shapes like this, **it is so much faster to place the coordinates from scratch**...
[Sample example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqT7d.png)